# Set CultureInfo.CurrentCulture sets also CurrentUICulture and vice versa

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, cultureinfo, currentculture, currentuiculture

For some reason, when setting in my app `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to 'de-CH', it automatically sets `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` to 'de-CH' too. If I do it the inverse way, it is happenning too. My system is in 'en-US'

```
    private void SetCurrentCultures(CultureInfo cultureInfo, CultureInfo cultureUiInfo)
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureUiInfo;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUiInfo;
    }
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, I set 'de-CH' to `CurrentCulture` and it sets `CurrentUICulture` too. After I set 'fr' to `CurrentUICulture`, it sets `CurrentCulture` to 'fr' too.

Does anyone know if this is a bug from Xamarin Forms, .NET or am I doing anything wrong?

**UPDATE**:

The problem is happening on a UWP app too, so it's not a XF issue.

Comment: Did you check a [remarks section of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-5.0#remarks)? _If you do set the property value to a `CultureInfo` object that represents a new culture, the value of the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` property also changes._

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: That's not about setting `CurrentUICulture` though. There are four properties here: two on `CultureInfo`, and two on `Thread.CurrentThread`. The question is about why setting `CurrentCulture` also changes `CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: Right @JonSkeet. Also in the other way. CurrentUICulture also changes CurrentCulture

Comment: On UWP app is happening too, not XF issue.

Comment: UWP apps do not distinguish between the current culture and the current UI culture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=net-5.0#the-current-ui-culture-and-uwp-apps